# как отправить в бот сообщение,которое будут видеть все пользователи

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

Мне нужно отправить в мой бот сообщение,которое будут видеть все пользователи бота.
Бот написан на python библиотека PyTelegramBotApi

Comment: Может, с циклом `for` поработать? `for i in список_пользователей:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно создать базу данный, где вы будете хранить `id` всех пользователей, которые подписались на него. Затем, с помощью `sqlite3`, вы будете выделять столбец с `id` и с помощью цикла, рассылать ВСЕМ пользователям нужное сообщение, фото, видео, стикер.

Comment: Разобрался как отослать фото,а как отослать фото? не знаю команды

Comment: Каким образом вы разобрались, как отослать фото, но не знаете как его отослать?)

Answer (score 0):

Нет, нельзя отправлять широковещательные сообщения с помощью бота(не используя костыли), так написано на [офф сайте](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#how-can-i-message-all-of-my-bot-39s-subscribers-at-once)

> How can I message all of my bot's subscribers at once?

> Unfortunately, at this moment we don't have methods for sending bulk
> messages, e.g. notifications. We may add something along these lines
> in the future.
>
> In order to avoid hitting our limits when sending out mass
> notifications, consider spreading them over longer intervals, e.g.
> 8-12 hours. The API will not allow bulk notifications to more than ~30
> users per second, if you go over that, you'll start getting 429
> errors.

Comment: А как это реализовать? может есть какие-то сервисы?

Comment: Где то советовали использовать [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto), но я не пользовался, так что смотрите сами.

Comment: Как возможное решение - создание канала для таких сообщений

Comment: Еще я нашел [эту](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/12/14/how-to-broadcast-telegram-messages-via-sap-cpi-and-telegram-bots/) статью. Советую такие вопросы искать в англоязычном сегменте интернета